# "Country" is to "national" as "city" is to…

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, analogy

How would I say something on a city level in comparison to a provincial level or national level?

> Elections are held *nationally* every four years, and _________ every two years.

Comment: In most cases "local" would be the term used.  However, there are cases where that would be ambiguous.

Comment: I said _provincially_ for state-wide or province-wide elections.

Comment: *Municipally* is the correct adverb to go in the sentence completion you gave. But to answer the (separate) title question, the typical noun used would be *resident*. *Local* is also possible, but not as widespread.

Comment: @SpecialSauce I think the title is using 'national' as a adjective rather than a noun.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A city is a completely different thing to a province, a distinction made in the question.

Comment: If you want to be accurate, use whatever term used by the locals, even if that means using foreign language terminology. If you expect your readers to be unfamiliar with the term, you can translate in parentheses or explain in introductory paragraph, but you and your readers can expect the translation/explanation to be slightly contrived unless they're already familiar with the local governances. For example: Pilpres (national presidential elections) are done every X years, pemilu legislatif (national legislative elections) every Y years, and pilkada (district chief elections) every Z years.

Comment: In generic terminology perspective, the only elections that have universally unambiguous terminologies are the main national election of the head of state and/or head of government, anything below that have regional variations that depends on the governance structure of that region. If you want correct terminology, you had to specify the country in the question.

Comment: "Regionally" might work. Though depending on context that could be considered to cover a larger area than a city.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

A city, viewed as a governmental and political entity, is called a *municipality* ([see Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/municipality)), with corresponding adjective *municipal* and adverb *municipally*. For example, we often speak of "municipal elections".

However, I must say that the sentence "elections are held municipally every two years" does not sound anywhere near as good to me as the sentence "elections are held nationally every four years"; I don't know why. So I'd suggest instead:

> National elections are held every four years, and municipal elections every two years.

---

Alternatively, in your example, you can use the phrase *at the city level*:

> Elections are held nationally every four years, and at the city level every two years.

Comment: One caveat: for most governmental things (elections as noted, laws/ordinances, police, courts, jails, water and sewer systems, electrical system, roads/streets, transit system, schools, etc.) municipal means city. But at least in the US *for bonds*, 'municipal bond' can mean anything below 'Federal'/national, including state/territory, county/parish, city/town, region, watershed, 'compacts' or 'authorities' of adjacent cities or even states across a border.

Comment: As Nicholas said, in American English, *locally* is generally used, so "elections are held locally every two years." To complicate matters some, we also have States. There the term is usually "State-wide."

Comment: @AMR: I actually live in the US, and I would *not* consider "locally" to be synonymous with "at the city level". Municipal elections are "local", but so are countywide ballot measures, district- and ward-level elections, and so on. ("State and local elections" means everything at the state level and below.)

Comment: @AMR Agreed with ruakh. We use 'local elections' to refer to elections for anything smaller than a state. This is most commonly city or county, but can be district, ward, parish, etc. depending on where you are.

Comment: Politics are _very_ far from my forte, but it should be noted in passing that municipalities are not necessarily equivalent to cities everywhere. Some countries have municipalities (or local entities referred to in English as municipalities) that either comprise only part of a city or encompass several cities/towns. This may not be a problem if you’re talking about a country like the US, but it could lead to inaccuracies in certain other countries. (Though I admit I’m not aware of anywhere that has non-city municipalities, but still holds city-level elections.)

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet +1 for mentioning this. In my country, for example, we have cities consisting of multiple municipalities and they have both municipal and city-level elections. Then, we have municipalities with several small towns inside and towns may have their own elections separate from municipal elections. Then we also have municipalities where the seat of municipality is inside of a town and the municipality covers both town and surrounding villages and municipal government is at the same time town government as well.

Comment: A city can be a municipality, but not all municipalities are cities - a municipality can refer to any kind of political jurisdiction (e.g. towns, conurbations, principalities) depending on where you are on Earth. I'd be inclined to use "at the city level" or "city-wide" to be unambiguous.

Answer (score 29):

**"municipal"** is the word you're looking for.

Elections are held nationally every four years, and **municipally** every two years.

> - [**municipal**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/municipal) (adj)  "of or relating to the government of a city or town"

e.g. Both national and municipal elections are held every four years in this country.

In some English speaking countries, mainly in the US, the term **"local elections"** is used more often than "municipal elections". See [**ngram**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=municipal+elections%2C+local+elections&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmunicipal%20elections%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clocal%20elections%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 22):

My preference would be for "locally"?

Comment: I would agree - 'Local Elections' seems to be the most used phrase these days: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=regional+elections%2Clocal+elections%2C+municipal+elections+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cregional%20elections%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clocal%20elections%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmunicipal%20elections%3B%2Cc0

Comment: At least in the case of the U.S., though, this can be ambiguous with counties (or other political subdivisions smaller than states,) especially in the case of elections. "Local election" (as well as "local government") refers to either city or county in common U.S. usage, so if you want to distinguish between them, 'local' isn't quite specific enough.

Comment: Welcome to ELU: what a good score for a first answer. For future reference: **never** answer a question with a sentence which ends in a question mark. The system automatically flags it as Low Quality, because answers should be real definitive answers, preferably with corroborative citations.

Comment: Local is also the term used in my electoral system, since these are the elections where we directly pick representatives in some immediate geographical level of governance.

Answer (score 3):

Another option you might use is "citywide":

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/citywide

> 1. occurring throughout a city; including an entire city: "**citywide** school board **elections**."
> 2. open to including, or affecting all the inhabitants of or groups in a city: "a citywide track meet."

http://www.answers.com/Q/What_are_citywide_elections :

> "An election where the ballot has choices for the city government (elected officials, proposed ordinances, bond issues, etc). "

Comment: From my non-native English I am under the impression that "citywide" highlights that something involves the whole city rather than just a part of it - f.ex. the whole city rather than just some districts; same concept for "nationwide", the whole nation rather than just some states / provinces / regions etc., or "worldwide", the whole world rather than just some nations. In this case "citywide" might not be what the OP is after, but I'm not sure that my interpretation is correct and I hope to use this opportunity to find out.

Comment: @SantiBailors is correct: "citywide school board elections" means that all 12 school districts in the city are holding school board elections, as opposed to only three of them. (Numbers made up out of whole cloth.)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context urban could be used to, I guess.
But seeing the other answers, it's probably not what you wanted ^^

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I wanted something to do with an election as in the example question. _The urban election_ does not make sense.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 Surely it doesn't, yes

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have pointed out, 'municipal' certainly works as the adjective in this case.

However, '**city**' itself can also be used (and, at least in the U.S., is frequently used) as the adjective.

For example, all of the following are perfectly normal usages:

- city government
- city elections
- city taxes
- city services

In this case, the word 'city' is used as an [attributive noun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attributive_noun) (also known as a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).)

At least in the case of the U.S., I would guess that just using 'city' as an attributive noun is more common than 'municipal,' though both are used frequently and the latter is probably considered more formal.

Answer (score 0):

In some situations, the word "civic" may also be used.

Comment: This post would be improved by explaining *why* you suggest this term, for example, by providing a dictionary definition or examples in the wild. I encourage you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.